# How to make my child object correctly rotate around the parent?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I previously had the below code, which I used to orientate my object towards where the right analog stick on my controller was (using the unity input system).

```
public void OnAim(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    aimDir = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
}

void HandleRotation()
{
    if (aimDir.magnitude >= 0.5f)
    {
        var aimAngle = Mathf.Atan2(aimDir.y, aimDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        rb.rotation = aimAngle;
    }
}
```

This worked by rotating the entire parent, however I now want to keep the parent object rotation fixed whilst just rotating the child object around it. I tried to rewrite the code:

```
void HandleRotation()
{
    if (aimDir.magnitude >= 0.5f)
    {
        var aimAngle = Mathf.Atan2(aimDir.y, aimDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        shootPoint.transform.RotateAround(transform.position, new Vector3(0, 0, 1), aimAngle);
    }
}
```

But this makes it constantly spin rather than just smoothly rotating towards where my right analog stick is facing. How do I fix this?

Comment: As the name says `RotateAround` doesn't **set** a rotation, it rotates from the current otation and adds an additional rotation ... I would suggest a different approach and simply add one more nesting level `parent -> rotationAnchor -> child` and simply rotate the rotation anchor instead ;)

Comment: @derHugo genius :) I somehow didn't think of this, please leave it as an answer and I'll mark it correct, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fistly, in this:

```
var aimAngle = Mathf.Atan2(aimDir.y, aimDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
```

Your aimAngle is not rad but degree so, i think you should use

```
rb.rotation = Qaternion.Eualar(aimAngle);
```

instead of

```
rb.rotation = aimAngle;
```

In your question, you could create an empty GameObject, put it in your child object(which you want to rotate)'s parent then put your child object in this empty object. Then rotate this empty object. This way, you have a rotating child object seems like parent turning and it is turning around it. Also, you awaided to rotate parent too.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `Vector3.RotateTowards()` and `localPosition`. Attach the `shootPoint` game object to a parent game object, attach a script with the following code to the parent object, and give the script a reference to `shootPoint`.

```
public Transform shootPoint;
public float distance = 2f;
public float speed = 5f;

private Vector3 _pos;
private Vector2 _aimDir;

public void OnAim(InputAction.CallbackContext context) =>
    aimDir = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();

private void Update()
{
    if (_aimDir.magnitude >= float.Epsilon) 
        _pos = new Vector3(_aimDir.x, 0f, _aimDir.y).normalized;

    shootPoint.localPosition =
            Vector3.RotateTowards(
                shootPoint.localPosition, 
                _pos * distance, 
                speed * Time.deltaTime, 
                0f);
}
```